# Google charts intermittently works in IE7

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I have created  chart that works fine in all browsers except IE7.  Every time I have made a change I checked it worked before making another change.  Once I was happy with the chart I set about adding a list elsewhere on the page (nothing fancy, just an unordered list with no styling) and when I went back to IE7 to check where on the page it was, the chart had disappeared.

I undid all of the changes I made to the page since I last knew it worked but nothing worked.  I even restored a previous version of the page that I knew worked but nope, still blank.  I went away to make a coffee, came back and refreshed the screen, and lo and behold the chart worked.  Checked again 5 minutes later without having changed anything and it stopped again.

```
google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
  google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
  function drawChart() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Grade', 'Target', 'Interim Target', 'Actual'],
      ['1',  70, 50,      <? echo $percentage1; ?>],
      ['2',  20, 40,     <? echo $percentage2; ?>],
      ['3',  10, 10,     <? echo $percentage3; ?>]
    ]);

    var options = {
      title: 'Grade Totals',
      colors: ['#B3C234', '#32CCFE', '#713973'],
      hAxis: {title: 'Grades', titleTextStyle: {color: 'black'}},
      vAxis: {title: 'Percentage', titleTextStyle: {color: 'black'}},
      "backgroundColor": { fill: "none" },
      'fontName' : '"Arial"',
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('grades_div'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
  }
```

I don't think there is anything wrong with the code, I haven't gone mad customising it.  I have been testing this using Windows 7 browser mode in IE10 on Windows 8.

Does anyone else have this type of problem?

Thanks

Comment: AFAIK Google discontinued support for IE < 9. Offer your users to use the Chrome Frame or to use a non-ancient browser.

Comment: FYI, the browser modes in IE developer tools don't actually render the page in, say, IE7 - they render the page with the constraints IE7 had (such as no border-radius). Rendering bugs and other issues will only be accurately represented by testing in an actual IE7 installation.

Comment: @Fabricio That's what I plan to do but you can lead a horse to water but you can't make them drink

Comment: @adam I guess I'll have to get some virtual machines going unless you know of a more efficient way?

Comment: @tatty27 no, we've had the same issues. It's like the browser detection vs feature detection argument - even if you can tell a browser supports a feature, you can't tell if it supports it cleanly enough so still need to browser detect.